# Missing UEFI Boot option entry

Tags: windows-10, uefi, bcd

#### Configuration

HP Omen 15

1 original HDD 1Tb with windows 10

1 M2 SSD 500Gb with Windows 10 Pro (I initially cloned HDD to SSD)

[See diskpart disk/vol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1919.jpg) - my main system is in Volume 4 (drive E:) on SSD

#### Issue

motherboard died and had to send the laptop for warranty repair (without the SSD). They replaced it.

When I put back my M2 SSD, UEFI couldn't detect its bootloader ([See UEFI Boot options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7vBx.jpg). Or [Basic boot device menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbLNA.jpg))

#### Temporary workarounds

For those who face the same issue, I do manage to boot on my SSD through one of the following way:

**- Best workaround:** using easyUEFI, I managed to update the existing "Windows Boot Manager" entry to target the SSD instead of the HDD
 - I added my SSD windows installation through my HDD windows system recovery menu, which had the effect of popping up a screen to let me choose between the 2 install at startup. I'm not happy as I'd like to be able to select the default system from the BIOS UEFI menu
 - I can access the SSD windows EFI file through the basic boot device menu ([See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn3Fi.jpg)). But it's not a stable solution

#### Expected result

I want 2 Windows Boot Manager entries into UEFI Boot options, 1 for each disk/system.

#### What I've tried

- rebuilding BCD through System recovery cmd with `diskpart` `bcdboot` and so on...
- playing with VisualBCD, but I'm afraid of destroying something

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated !

Comment: It looks to me as if your default BIOS boot is the first option in the menu you call "basic boot device menu", while it should be the fourth entry.

Comment: I don't think that the order in this menu would change much. My issue is that I'm missing a "Windows Boot Manager" related to Windows installed on my SSD

Answer (score 0):

We can try to troubleshoot the issue as below:

1. Remove the HDD from your computer and install only the SSD on your computer.
2. Enter BIOS to view if we can see SSD. If so, check if we can select to boot from the SSD first. If so, install the HDD into computer, then view if we can boot from SSD.
3. If we can not see SSD in BIOS, we need to find such a setting in BIOS in order to see SSD.
4. If we can not find such a setting or the setting is not existing, because we replace the motherboard, maybe we need to update BIOS from the laptop for warranty repair.